# math - Get image dimension after rotation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

This is all about mathematics. It's a shame that I'v forgotten those I learned in scool.

OK, I'm trying to get the image dimension after rotation (using canvas) with a certain angle in Javascript.

[image]

Comment: (100+40*Math.sqrt(3))*(100*Math.sqrt(3)+40)

Comment: what does 3 stand for? where did the angle go?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since I don't have any tools other than MSPaint here, I'll re-use your image:

[image]

Say your original rectangle's size is R(ectangle)W(idth) * RH(eight),

in this case `RW=200`, `RH=80`;

After rotating a certain angle A, counterclockwise,

where `0deg <= A <= 90deg` in degrees (or `0 <= A <= Math.PI/2` in radians),

in this case `A=30deg` or `A=Math.PI/6`,

In the new "outer" rectangle, each side is divided by two parts (for the convenience of describing; corresponding to the image).

On the left side, let's say the upper (**purple**) part is called N(ew)H(eight)U(p), and the lower (**red**) part is called NHL(ow);

Same rule on the bottom side, we have NW(idth)L(eft) (**blue**) and NWR(ight) (**orange**).

So the size (area) of new rectangle would be `(NHU + NHL) * (NWL + NWR)`

According to the definition of `sin` and `cos`:

```
NWL = RW * Math.cos(A); //where A is in radians
NHL = RW * Math.sin(A);

NHU = RH * Math.cos(A);
NWR = RH * Math.sin(A);
```

(if you're using `A` in degrees, replace `A` to `Math.PI*A/180`).

So the new "outer" width would be `NWL + NWR`, and new "outer" height would be `NHU + NHL`, and now you can calculate everything.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer. typo: NWR should be **RH** * Math.sin(A);

Answer (score 4):

Here's a drop-in function that implements @Passerby's solution + a couple other safeguards:

```js
function imageSizeAfterRotation(size, degrees) {
    degrees = degrees % 180;
    if (degrees < 0) {
        degrees = 180 + degrees;
    }
    if (degrees >= 90) {
        size = [ size[1], size[0] ];
        degrees = degrees - 90;
    }
    if (degrees === 0) {
        return size;
    }
    const radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    const width = (size[0] * Math.cos(radians)) + (size[1] * Math.sin(radians));
    const height = (size[0] * Math.sin(radians)) + (size[1] * Math.cos(radians));
    return [ width, height ];
}

// USAGE:
imageSizeAfterRotation([ 200, 80 ], 30) // [ 213.20508075688775, 169.28203230275508 ]
```